# Java Port scanner

Tags: java

```
import java.net.Socket;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
       String remote = "69.163.44.171";
       int i = 0;
       do {
       try {
       Socket s = new Socket(remote,i);
       System.out.println("Server is listening on port " + i+ " of " + remote);
       s.close();

       } catch (IOException ex) {
       System.out.println("Server is not listening on port " + i+ " of " + remote);
    }
       i++;
       } while(i == 55000);
}
```

Output:

```
Server is not listening on port 0 of 69.163.44.171
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

i use while loop cause it is faster, now to the question why does it only scan one port?

Comment: compiler error: missing `;` after `while(i == 55000)`  and using a normal `for` would make the code more readable...

Comment: (a) This program is network-bound. How you loop is entirely irrelevant to its performance.

(b) This is a 'do' loop not a 'while' loop.

(c) Faster than what? Why?

Comment: This while loop is so fast it doesn't even loop.

Comment: A logic mistake got 2 upvotes? I smell socks...

Answer (score 3):

Well... how often *did* you think the condition `while(i == 55000)` would be `true`?

Answer (score 2):

You need to change to this for your while:

```
while(i <= 55000)
```

Currently you're reaching i (which is 1) != 55000, so you drop out of the loop.

Answer (score 2):

This part:

```
} while(i == 55000)
```

will repeat the loop **as long as** `i` is **exactly** 55000.

Since `i` starts out as 0 and is incremented to 1 after that, it will never reach that place with a value of exactly 55000 and thus never re-start the loop.

Answer (score 1):

You are saying `while(i == 55000)` instead of `while(i <= 55000)`

Answer (score 0):

The while condition bug has been noted in several answers, so I won't repeat it. I might make one suggestion though: you may be able to make this faster if you use a [Selector](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/nio/channels/Selector.html) and some [SocketChannels](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/nio/channels/SocketChannel.html) rather than trying one at a time. [Here's](http://rox-xmlrpc.sourceforge.net/niotut/) some reading material.